Flutter: Is the title property of the MaterialApps class not used on Android 10+?
Is the title property of the MaterialApp class meaningless not only on iOS, but also on Android 10 or later? It seems to be, but I cannot find an official explanation for it.
When I run the following code ...
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

... I can see the title "Flutter Demo" in the recent apps screen on Android 9, but not on Android 10.



Android 9
Android 10









